# is it possible to know if ui.multiselect is active on an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, multi-select

I've a Select, I applied to it a multiselect jquery plugin.
But I need to know in my code if the object **$('#slcUsers')** is already a ui.multiselect.
But I cannot figure out how to understand the first time I pass on my code, if it's already a multiselect object, or still a simple select.

Simply, the html code

```
<select name="slcUsers[]" id="slcUsers" multiple="multiple" style="display:none;"></select>
```

and here the javascript

```
$("#slcUsers").multiselect({sortable: false});
```

this is the plugin I'm talking about [multiselect jquery](https://github.com/ehynds/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
if(!$("#slcUsers").data('echMultiselect'))
    $("#slcUsers").multiselect({sortable: false});
```

Comment: it's not working, the select has not the class ui-multiselect. it's been created a div with that class, i will check that

Comment: this is a better control `if($('div.ui-multiselect').length)`

Comment: So which multiselect plugin are you using?

Answer (score 0):

To check the multiple select properties in jquery

```
$('#slcUsers').prop('multiple')
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CaVcu/)